# Why are fangs of girls so common in anime?

Tags: tropes

In many anime, the girls there have fangs.

- Kiriha from *Tsugumomo*
  [image]
- Rika from *Kanojo mo Kanojo*
  [image]
- Senko and Shiro from *The Helpful Fox Senko-san*
  [image: List item]

Why are fangs of girls so common in anime?

Comment: I feel like there's a fair number of boys with fangs as well.  Generally seems to be a thing with younger characters, regardless of gender.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman well yeah maybe but wikipedia says 'In Japan it is perceived as a sign of youthfulness and natural beauty.[1][2] In 2013 it had become a trend where teenage girls would undergo dental procedures to cap the upper canines.[3]'

Comment: Because it is cute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're called Yaeba. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaeba) says:

> In Japan, yaeba (八重歯, "double tooth") are human teeth, especially upper canines, with an uncommonly fang-like appearance. Yaeba most often refers to a tooth overlapping another tooth or protruding from higher in the gum. In Japan it is perceived as a sign of youthfulness and natural beauty. In 2013 it had become a trend where teenage girls would undergo dental procedures to cap the upper canines.

Comment: What does it mean to 'cap the upper canines'? To make them more apparent?

Comment: @Michael good question but no idea. i think biology or medical/health stackexchange for this.

Comment: @Michael: A [dental cap or crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_(dental_restoration)) involves essentially putting a false tooth on top of the existing tooth. In this case, they are essentially increasing the size of the canines. I personally know someone who has a cap to cover a twisted tooth and one to cover broken "dead" teeth. You can see before and after pictures [here](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/02/01/yaeba-japanese-double-tooth-trend-expensive-crooked-smile_n_2596720.html) for this particular operation.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [BCLC's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/67362/36158), the girls in the *The Helpful Fox Senko-san* are [kitsune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune), aka fox spirits.

Foxes have [fangs](https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/red-fox-showing-it-teeth-picture-id642199518?s=612x612). They, along with many of the other fox/wolf/cat/dog-human hybrids that show up in anime, have fangs as part of their "not-fully-human" character design.